# non root ssh keys

Tags: ssh, centos, openssh

I'm having issues setting up a different CentOS account with its own pair of SSH keys.
I have created the required files but when connecting with Putty it says Connection refused, here's the putty log:

```
2013-03-31 23:09:14 Looking up host "XXX.XXXXXX.XXXXX"
2013-03-31 23:09:14 Connecting to XX.XX.XXX.XXX port 22
2013-03-31 23:09:14 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
2013-03-31 23:09:14 Using SSH protocol version 2
2013-03-31 23:09:14 We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.62
2013-03-31 23:09:14 Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
2013-03-31 23:09:15 Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
2013-03-31 23:09:15 Host key fingerprint is:
2013-03-31 23:09:15 ssh-rsa XXXX XX:6s:18:67:a3:39:39:95rn:21:p1:9b:12:4b:1p:24
2013-03-31 23:09:15 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
2013-03-31 23:09:15 Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
2013-03-31 23:09:15 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
2013-03-31 23:09:15 Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
2013-03-31 23:09:15 Reading private key file "C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\SSH-Key.ppk"
2013-03-31 23:09:15 Offered public key
2013-03-31 23:09:15 Server refused our key
2013-03-31 23:09:15 Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL
2013-03-31 23:09:15 Attempting GSSAPI authentication
2013-03-31 23:09:16 GSSAPI authentication request refused
2013-03-31 23:09:16 Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this superuser.com question along with it's answers: 
[putty 0.61: why do I see “Access Denied” message after I enter my login id?](https://superuser.com/questions/312197/)

Sounds like an issue with your particular version of PuTTY. Make sure you're using 0.62 or higher.

- http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/gssapi-access-denied.html

This appears to be a bug with version 0.61 of PuTTY.

> **summary:** Spurious "Access denied" printed in the PuTTY window after GSSAPI failure
>
> **class:** bug: This is clearly an actual problem we want fixed.
>
> **difficulty:** fun: Just needs tuits, and not many of them.
>
> **priority:** high: This should be fixed in the next release.
>
> **absent-in:** 0.60 present-in: 0.61 fixed-in: r9232 0.62

Comment: When you reference an answer on another site, you should summarize the answer in your answer.

Comment: Didn't seem necessary given the other site was a stackexchange site but I added some additional details anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The important part is:

```
2013-03-31 23:09:15 Offered public key
2013-03-31 23:09:15 Server refused our key
```

That means: the client sent the public key, but server rejected it for some reason. To find out why the server rejected the key, **you need to look into the server's log**, typically `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth.log` on Linux systems.

The most common reason for such rejection is that users (other than the one you're logging in as) have write access to one or more of the following:

- the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys file`
- the `~/.ssh` directory
- the user's home directory.

For new users of SSH, it might seem counter-intuitive that SSH key authentication stops working if you give the relevant files or directories too much access. This is a security feature: if the list of authorized SSH keys is writable by anyone other than the owner of the user account, a malicious user might just drop in his/her key and would then have unrestricted access to that account. In this situation, `sshd` simply stops accepting key authentication for that user at all until the permission problem is fixed (and the list of authorized keys hopefully checked for tampering).